# Visual Studio Not Creating Executable (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have been changing things on the project options and now when I build my project instead of getting an executable I'm getting these files

[image: The Folder]

Comment: What is displayed in the Output window?

Comment: Look at the output screen. Press Alt-2 to get it. The name (and location) of the executable should be in the output.

Comment: Try looking at the output folder in the root of the solution folder. Example: `%solution%\DEBUG` instead of `%solution%\Project1\DEBUG`.

Comment: Thank you Cocarin, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was looking inside

> %solution%\Project1\DEBUG

instead of

> %solution%\DEBUG

Thank you everyone who tried to help me!